# Iterating over large collections in C#: Taking very long

Tags: c#, wpf, collections, iteration

I recently started a WPF application. I connected that to a BaseX (XML-based) database and retrieved about one million entries from it. I wanted to iterate over the entries, calculate something for each entry and then write that back to the database:

```
IEnumerable<Result> resultSet = baseXClient.Query("...", "database");
foreach (Result result in resultSet) 
{
    ...
}
```

The problem: The inside of the foreach is never reached. the Query() method returns pretty fast, but when the foreach is reached C# seems to do SOMETHING with the collection, the code is not continuing for a very very long time (at least 10 minutes, never let it run any longer).
What's going on here?
I tried to limit the number of items retrieved. When retrieving 100.000 results, the same thing occurs but the code continues after about 10-20 seconds. When retrieving the full one million results, C# seems to be stuck forever...

Any ideas?
regards

**Edit: Why this is happening**
As some of you pointed out, the reason for this behavior seems to be that the query is actually only evaluated when `MoveNext()` on the Enumerator inside the Enumerable is called. My database seems unable to return one value at a time, but instead returns the entire one million dataset at once. I will try to switch to another database (Apache Lucene, if possible, as it has good fulltext search support) and edit this post to let you know if it changed anything.
PS: Yes, I am aware that one million results is a lot. This is not meant for live usage, it is just a step for preparing the data. While I didn't expect the code to run in a few seconds, I was still surprised to see SUCH poor performance in the database.

**Edit: The Solution** So I migrated the XML database to Apache Lucine. Works like a charm! Of course Lucine is a text-based database that is not suitable for every use case, but for me it worked wonders. Can iterate over one million entries in a few seconds, one entry per loop is fetched - works extremly well!

Comment: [deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx).

Comment: @codesparkle, good info, but I wonder why it seems his entire query must run before the first item will be returned.

Comment: Please consider posting more code, and a minor sample of the data.

Comment: The best shot is probably to retrieve the values directly into a native array or Hash list and operate on it, if you need more help you can paste more code.

Comment: see edit for how I solved the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One million of anything is a lot... so any operation that obtains that many items is expected to take significant amount of time. It looks like library you use does not defer retrieving items till it is absolutely necessary - so you see impact of getting all items hidden behind "foreach" statement.

What happens:

"foreach" is not a single operation, but rather several calls on IEnumerable and IEnumerator: IEnumerable.GetEnumerator, repeated calls to IEnumerator.MoveNext.

First call `GetEnumerator` may be implemented with deferred execution (most common way how LINQ queries are written) or immediate execution (which seem to be the case of your collection.

Calls to MoveNext could also trigger immediate execution of whole query even if you are asking just for single item or each call can get just single item. I.e. most LINQ queries get just one next item from iterator.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough info. It seems you are right. If I use MoveNext() manually, this is where everything gets blocked. It seems the database does not support getting only a single item - a shame. Will try another database and report back in my original post.

Answer (score 5):

Let me quess - you are NOT loading the data when youcreate the rsultSet, but when it is first accessed (delayed execution), and loading one million entries you just take a lot of time to deserialize them into memory.

Welcome to the inefficiences of XML databases.

Comment: Well, it was said that BaseX would be pretty fast, but I will try taking the data into a Apache Lucene database today and see if that speeds up things. You are right than one million is a lot, and I don't expect them to be returned within seconds, but I don't expect them to take 10+ minutes either.

Comment: I hate to tell you, but that is a very harsh requirement. Seriously. 1ms per item comes out at 1000 seconds, which IS 10 seconds. 1ms is not that much for "xml", which is notoriously inefficient to deal with to start with, so depending on the size of the XML it may easily take longer.

Answer (score 2):

The answers here all point to the cause of your perceived problem with foreach (deferred execution), but not to a possible solution. I'm not sure if this database supports it, but one solution might be to try paging the results in smaller batches, rather than getting the whole chunk of data at once.

An alternative is to write a database query which performs the necessary calculations, so that your database never needs to send 1 million records anywhere. (Again, not sure if this database supports that)

Comment: Thank you. You are right, there are probably more sophisticated solutions to what I am doing here. Still, I'm surprised that the database takes THAT long for retrieving the items. Unfortunately, I can get the data in batches but since I have to perform an UPDATE query for each dataset, which unfortunately cannot be parallelized, that won't help much.

Answer (score 0):

To force the query to be evaluated before the foreach, call the ToList function on your resultSet. (wont solve your problem if the problem is the database taking forever)

Comment: Calling `ToList`, `ToArray` or `ToDictionary` has the same effect.

Comment: Calling `Count` will indeed evaluate it, but if you later `foreach` over it then you're getting a new `IEnumerator` that needs to be evaluated, meaning you're now doing the query twice.  If you just `ToList`/`ToArray`/etc the data and then `foreach` it you'll eagerly fetch the data and only fetch it once.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try a more traditional for loop to see if that would work?

```
IEnumerable<Result> resultSet = baseXClient.Query("...", "database");
for (int x =0; x < resultSet.Count; x++)
{
    Result result = resultSet[x];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Differed execution is what's going on here; this won't change that.  On top of that, this won't compile as an `IEnumerable` doesn't have a `Count` property, or an indexer.

Comment: right. Count (after using ToList()) or MoveNext() on the Enumerator both block the execution - so there seems no way around that.